# Break one row with jQuery each [Bootstrap | JSON]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty novice with jQuery and I have a question which is bothering me lately.

I'm using jQuery + Bootstrap + JSON to create a page, and output the results in Bootstrap Grid. I don't know how to describe it but I'll try to write it in code.

Here is what I want to achieve the output.

```
<div id = "appendClasses">
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-4"><p>Party 1</p></div>
<div class = "col-md-4"><p>Party 2</p></div>
<div class = "col-md-4"><p>Party 3</p></div>
</div>
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-4"><p>Party 4</p></div>
<div class = "col-md-4"><p>Party 5</p></div>
<div class = "col-md-4"><p>Party 6</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The list goes on and on.

I have HTML like this.

```
<div id = "appendClasses"></div>
```

And the jQuery to produce the HTML and inject it into the `#appendClasses`.

```
$.getJSON(partyURL, function(partyURLResponse) {
    var partyHTML = '';
$.each(partyURLResponse.data, function(partyIdx, party) {
        /*optional stuff to do after success */
       partyHTML += '<div class = "row">';
       partyHTML += '<div class = "col-md-4">';
       partyHTML += '<p>' + party.id + '</p>';
       partyHTML += '</div>';
       partyHTML += '</div>';
        partyHTML += '</div>';
    });
    $('#appendClasses').html(partyHTML);
  });
```

This is how it outputs.

```
<div id = "appendClasses">
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-4"><p>Party 1</p></div>
</div>
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-4"><p>Party 2</p></div>
</div>
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-4"><p>Party 3</p></div>
</div>
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-4"><p>Party 4</p></div>
</div>
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-4"><p>Party 5</p></div>
</div>
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-4"><p>Party 6</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

So it is showing the results in one line without the grid. How can I fix this?

Comment: how about making a counter?

Comment: Tried with if loop. It doesn't show the result I want.

Comment: I did. I put the if to break one row (after class = "row" like you mentioned), still the same result though.

Comment: I think you need a nested loop in this scenario.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate? I'm still struggling with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, you're adding `<div class='row'>`, to each party, you can solve it by carefully count the current id, and:

1. When the current index is at start of a row, do `partyHTML += '<div class = "row">';`
2. When row item is full or the loop ends with a not empty row, do `partyHTML += '</div>';` to close it.

For example:

```
var count = 0;
var item_per_row = 3;
$.each(partyURLResponse.data, function(partyIdx, party) {
   /*optional stuff to do after success */
   if (count === 0) { // Start of a row
    partyHTML += '<div class = "row">';
   }
   partyHTML += '<div class = "col-md-4">';
   partyHTML += '<p>' + party.id + '</p>';
   partyHTML += '</div>';

   ++count;
   if (count === item_per_row) {  // End of row
    partyHTML += '</div>';
   }

   // It seems you mistakenly closed one more div in loop
   // is it a typo?
   // partyHTML += '</div>';
});
if (count > 0) {  // Close the last row if it exist.
  partyHTML += '</div>';
}

$('#appendClasses').html(partyHTML);
```

However, it would be hard to maintain as you use plain text to manage the code (as you seems to add one additional `</div>` in each iteration), as you're using jQuery, I'd suggest you use its apis to manage the dom elements and their attributes...etc, which would be more easy to maintain and do future changes.

```js
var parties = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3},
  {id: 4},
  {id: 5}
];
// Items per row.
var items_per_row = 3;
// current item counts in a row.
var item_count = 0;

// Create a row to place the created divs
var $row = $('<div>').addClass('row');

// Get target to place these items.
var $target = $('#appendClasses');
$.each(parties, function(partyIdx, party) {
  /*optional stuff to do after success */
  // Just use jquery's function to create the dom elements would be more clear.
  
  var div = $('<div>');            // Create div.
  
  var p = $('<p>').text(party.id);  // Create p and add text to it.
  div
    .addClass('col-md-4')     // add class `col-md-4` to div
    .append(p)                         // append the p to the div
    .appendTo($row);           // append the div to the row.
  
  ++item_count;
  
  // When item count reach limit, append row to target
  // and create a new row for later elements.
  if (item_count === items_per_row) {    
    $row.appendTo($target);
    $row = $('<div>').addClass('row');
    item_count = 0;
  }
});

if (item_count > 0) {
  $row.appendTo($target);
}
```

```css
.row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  padding: 10px;
  width : 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "appendClasses"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use each in other each body, when json structure will be like here it is - my fast [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iNPAHJDea6UWUyTTTvEh?p=preview) code.
And you can return from server array of arrays, then it will be nice to parse and render it like you need.

```
[
  [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}],
  [{id: 4}, {id: 5}, {id: 6}]
]
```

and then this code will be work nice:

```
$.each(partyURLResponse.data, function(partyIdx, party) {
    /*optional stuff to do after success */
    partyHTML += '<div class = "row">';

    $.each(party, function(id, item) {
      partyHTML += '<div class = "col-md-4">';
      partyHTML += '<p>' + item.id + '</p>';
      partyHTML += '</div>';
    });

    partyHTML += '</div>';
  });

  $('#appendClasses').append(partyHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with minimal code. I have left inline comments to denote what each line does.

```js
var parties = [{id: 'p1'},{id: 'p2'},{id: 'p3'},{id: 'p4'},{id: 'p5'},{id: 'p6'}],
 //Create empty containers for later use
 $html = $rows = $(),
 //Break limit
    colsPerWrap = 3;

$.each(parties, function(partyIdx, party) {
 //Create a jQuery object with the desired content
    var $col = $("<div/>", {
        'class': 'col-md-4',
        'html': '<p>' + party.id + '</p>'
    });
 //Add the created object to the container
    $rows = $rows.add($col);
 //At every break limit
    if ( (partyIdx+1) % colsPerWrap === 0 ) {
     //Append the cols to the inner wrapper
        var $wrap = $("<div/>", { 'class': 'row' });
        $wrap.append($rows);
     //Empty the container for the next iteration
        $rows = $();
     //Populate the container with each inner wrapper
        $html = $html.add($wrap);
    }
});
//Always append outside the loop as DOM scan is expensive!
$('#appendClasses').empty().append($html);
```

```css
.row {
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "appendClasses"></div>
```